# How to show partial view with parameter on click

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a database with people and phones and i created a partial view that shows persons phones. I want this patial view to be loaded on click at some button like ShowPhones or something like that.

This is how i call view
    @Html.Partial("ShowPersonsPhones", item.phones)

This is my partial view

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.Phone>

<h2>Parial View</h2>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Numer)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Model)
    </th>
</tr>
@foreach (var phone in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(item => phone.Numer)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(item => phone.Model)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

EDIT:
i tried to do some javascript in view but it just doesnt work

```
<style>
.shown{
    display : inline;
}
.hidden{
    display : none;
}
</style>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_partial(i) {
    alert("show partial " + i);
    var divsname = '#partial' + i;
    div = $(divsname);
    if (div.hasClass('hidden'))
    {
        div.removeClass("shown");
        div.addClass("hidden");
    }
    else
    {
        div.removeClass('hidden');
        div.addClass("shown");
    }
}
</script>
```

When i put alert in the function it shows but doesnt change classes for some reason.

Comment: The logic in your script is wrong - (it would need to be `if (div.hasClass('shown'))`) however all this is unnecessary, and all you need to `$(yourButton).click(function() { $(yourDiv).toggle() });` to toggle the visibility (although its unclear what the `i` is in your script

Comment: I have variable i in function becouse there are multiple <div>s in which i want to render partial view on button click. These divs have id's based on some numbers. I "debbuged" it in browser and my script doesnt want to change classes of element. After chenging the logic in the if it still doesnt work.

Comment: Do not use `id` elements - use class names and relative selectors. You need to show the actual code you are using to reproduce your problem (nowhere in your question are there any elements with `<div id="partial#">`

Answer (score 0):

In button click event, you can load the partial view.

**ViewPage**

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="ClickMe" onclick="loadPartialView()" />
<div id="partialDiv"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function loadPartialView() {
        $("#partialDiv").load('@Url.Action("IndexView","Home")');
    }
</script>
```

In Controller, you can return the partial view with the parameter.

```
public ActionResult IndexView()
        {
            return PartialView("_PartialView", db.Phones.ToList());
        }
```

Comment: I tried to make the wanted element hidden by display none and then show it using javascript but for some reason i cant make it work.